# How to Change Document Root In PHP?

Tags: php, server

Actually I tried to change document root in php?

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = "C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Infogreen/";
```

The above code is working. But when i am trying to copy from variable is not working. I can't find the mistake.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = $_GET[path];
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: your `DocumentRoot` is set up by your server, unless you change your server config, I dont think it is possible in this way

Comment: Why do you want to change your `DocumentRoot`? Maybe we can help you with your actual goal instead of this "unusual" solution to something. There must be some end goal to this. Let's solve that instead.

Comment: Really thank you @KyleDomingo. Actually In Extplorer  i need chnage path based on url parameter. So that i looking for the solution.

Comment: Are you making a file manager using PHP? Is that what you mean by "chnage path based on url parameter"?

Comment: Exactly correct. I am using eXtplorer script .

Answer (score 1):

The document root is not set in PHP, it's set by the Webserver. If you use Apache, you can find the `DocumentRoot` directive in the apache config.